# How can I limit a hierarchical query to the point where there are multiple children?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, hierarchy

*This question is related to my [previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64350/how-can-i-select-rows-from-a-hierarchical-query-with-the-lowest-level/) about hierarchical queries.*

I have a hierarchical query in Oracle 11gR2 that returns something like this:

```
- Level 1
  - Level 2
    - Level 3
      - Level 4
        - Level 5
          - Level 6
      - Level 4
        - Level 5
          - Level 6
            - Level 7
```

I'd like to design a query to return the rows for levels 1-3, on the basis that there are two siblings at level 4. Or, to put it another way, I'd like to return all the rows in the hierarchy, starting from a given point, until I reach a level with more than one sibling. I'd then like to stop there, excluding the level with multiple siblings.

I've tried putting `count` functions in various places in my query, but I can't work it out. This is what I have so far:

```
select   *
  from
    (select   level, count (*) over (partition by level) level_count, <columns>
      from <tables>
        start with <predicate>
        connect by prior <child> = <parent>
    )
  where level_count = 1;
```

This works for the case there the length of each branch is the same, but returns extra rows otherwise. In my example above, I want to return only the rows for levels 1-3 (i.e. 3 rows in total) and exclude level 7 because level 4 has two siblings. I hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified with window functions:

```
with hier as
    (select   level as the_level, <columns>
      from <tables>
        start with <predicate>
        connect by prior <child> = <parent>
    ), levels as
    (select hier.*, count(*) over (order by the_level) as count_items
      from hier
    )
  select levels.*
    from levels
    where the_level = count_items ;
```

Comment: I had to qualify the `select *` as `select hier.*`, but other than that your query is great - thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, thnx. That's an Oracle quirk I had forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've worked it out:

```
with hier as
    (select   level as the_level, <columns>
      from <tables>
        start with <predicate>
        connect by prior <child> = <parent>
    ), maxlev as
    (select   the_level as max_level
      from
        (select   the_level, count( * )
          from hier
          group by the_level
          having count( * ) > 1
          order by the_level
        )
      where rownum = 1
    )
  select   hier.*
    from hier, maxlev
    where the_level < max_level;
```